# how to make it fast when deleting a document in sub collection in Firestore after using http trigger?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to perform a cron job to delete an event that has passed. before deleting the event document, I want to delete the users that give like to that event

so ...

1. first I need to query documents of the events that have passed
2. access the sub collection of that event to get the userIDs of the likers
3. delete the eventID in the users sub collection "likedEvents"
4. finally delete that passed event document

user `1wBZMVjxS0l5ass977c4` gives like to event  `N5zH0lauf7reNlV9qFe3`

Events Collection:
[image]

Users Collection:
[image]

the problem is, it seems take to much time to perform this action:

> Function execution took 11656 ms, finished with status code: 200

I just have one event to be deleted, but it takes 11s. I don't know if it is normal, or maybe I have a bad code like below?

here is the code I use:

```
    export const cronJobDeletingPastEvents3456 = functions.https.onRequest(async (request,response) => {


    try {

        const db = admin.firestore()
        const dateNow = new Date()
        const pastEvents = await db.collection("events").where('dateTimeFinish', '<', dateNow).get()

        if (pastEvents.docs.length === 0) {
            response.send(" there are no events have passed recent date")
        } else {

            pastEvents.forEach(async snap => {

                const eventID = snap.data().eventID
                const likersSnapshots = await snap.ref.collection("likers").get()
                const likersDocuments = likersSnapshots.docs

                const likersIDs = []

                likersDocuments.forEach(likersSnap => {
                    const userIDLikers = likersSnap.data().userID
                    likersIDs.push(userIDLikers)
                })

                const promisesDeletingLikers = []

                likersIDs.forEach(likerUserId => {
                    const likersEventRef = db.collection('users').doc(likerUserId).collection('likedEvents').doc(eventID)
                    const p = likersEventRef.delete()
                    promisesDeletingLikers.push(p)

                })

                await Promise.all(promisesDeletingLikers)
                await snap.ref.delete() 

            })

            // send response
            response.send("Successfully performing cron job")

        }



    }
    catch (error) {
        response.status(500).send(error)
    }



})
```

Comment: I have been running some test on another application, using Datastore, and I found no reason why it should be that slow, everything was working just fine and fast for me. As you said, it may be related to your code, I see you have some nested loops in there that may be making it slower.